# different page Navigation in ListView.builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation, flutter-listview, flutter-routes

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Animals()));
},
```

I am trying to add different page routing Navigation in Inkwell insider
I tried some different ways But it doesn't work

My List View name

```
List title = [
   'Animals',
   'Birds',
   'Body Parts',
   'Country',
   'Fish',
   'Plants',
   'Vehicle',
   'Works',
];
```

I want this to navigate to
`List route = [Animals(),Birds(),BodyParts(),Country(),Fish(),Plant(),Vehicle(),Works(),];`

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do :

```
List pages = [['Animals',Animals()],['Birds',Birds()],['Body Parts',BodyParts()], 
             ['Country',Country()],['Fish',Fish()],['Vehicle',Vehicle()], 
             ['Plants',Plants()],['Works',Works()]];
```

now :

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: pages.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: ListTile(title:Text(pages[index][0])),
          onTap: () {
           Navigator.push(context,MaterialpageRoute(builder:(context)=>pages[index][1])));
          },
          
        );
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have these lists:

```
List<String> title = ['Animals', 'Birds', 'Body Parts', 'Country', 'Fish', 'Plants', 'Vehicle', 'Works'];

List<Widget> route = [Animals(), Birds(), BodyParts(), Country(), Fish(), Plant(), Vehicle(), Works()];
```

Now, You can simply map the widgets using index in ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: title.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
            title: title[index],
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => route[index]))
        );
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: title.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //YOUR NAVIGATION CODE
              },
              child: Text('${title[index]}'),
            );
          },
        )
```